# Best practice for a marketplace/advertisment web-application made in GWT

Tags: gwt, guice, mvp, requestfactory, shiro

I'm thinking about making a marketplace/advertisment website using GWT. I've got little experience using GWT but I do like it. Not really experienced with EE-applications either.

However I've done some reading and it seems to be that RequestFactory is the thing. And MVP, and Guice, and GIN, and Shiro (for authentication)

I'm not really sure how to combine all these. I'm thinking about using plain SQL server using JDBC, had thoughts about using an ORM such as Hibernate aswell.

Anyway, would it be good to combine GWT(RequestFactory+MVP) + Guice + GIN + Shiro? I'm I missing out something? Atm it feels like there are several techniques I'm not accustomed to. Which mans I must do quite a lot of reading and it feels kinda hard to combine all those, if its even possible?

//Johan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have little experience with GWT I would recommend that you keep it simple and use GWT-RPC for client-server communication, no MVP, no Guice/Gin, no Shiro, unless you can afford to spend weeks learning and battling these frameworks. I've worked with GWT for a few years and my personal opinion is that most of these tools are overkill and get in the way more than they help, especially for small projects (and sometimes even for big ones).

Comment: What about keeping track of history, what would you recommend for that? Command pattern or using Activies & Places. I kinda got the feeling that MVP+Activies&Places would be best for keeping track of history?

Comment: I personally use Activies & Places without the whole MVP thing. I put unit-testable code in activites which play a role analogous to presenters in MVP, but with less overhead imo.